# Calculating Hurst Exponent with energy data (aFRR) - Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with calculating the Hurst Exponent. My Datas are aFRR datas from Entsoe and they are including positive and negative values.

```
def hurst(ts):
    lags = range(1, len(ts)-1)
    tau = [numpy.sqrt(numpy.std(numpy.subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]
    poly = numpy.polyfit(numpy.log(lags), numpy.log(tau), 1)
    return poly[0]*2.0
```

For poly I alway get values like [-0.06522701,  2.0348634 ]. And so my hurst Exponente is alway negative, but it should be between 0 and 1.
If you need more information, please let me know. I'm really new in the python community and I'm not sure if this informations are enough to solve my problem.

Comment: I don't think it's a Python-related problem. Maybe a polynomial fit is not the best choice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Test this code:

```
log(cumsum(random.randn(100000)+1)+1000)
```

Because above line keeps your hurst between 0 and 1.

```
def hurst(p):  
    tau = []; lagvec = []  
    #  Step through the different lags  
    for lag in range(2,20):  
        #  produce price difference with lag  
        pp = subtract(p[lag:],p[:-lag])  
        #  Write the different lags into a vector  
        lagvec.append(lag)  
        #  Calculate the variance of the differnce vector  
        tau.append(sqrt(std(pp)))  
    #  linear fit to double-log graph (gives power)  
    m = polyfit(log10(lagvec),log10(tau),1)  
    # calculate hurst  
    hurst = m[0]*2  
    # plot lag vs variance  
    #py.plot(lagvec,tau,'o'); show()  
    return hurst  
if __name__=="__main__":  
    #  Different types of time series for testing  
    #p = log10(cumsum(random.randn(50000)+1)+1000) # trending, hurst ~ 1  
    #p = log10((random.randn(50000))+1000)   # mean reverting, hurst ~ 0  
    p = log10(cumsum(random.randn(50000))+1000) # random walk, hurst ~ 0.5  
    print( hurst(p)  )
```

[Timeseries Similarity-Hurst-ADF-Basics-of-Statistical-Mean-Reversion-Testing](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Basics-of-Statistical-Mean-Reversion-Testing/)
Check your dataset, specially series average value.

[HURST](https://w3.ual.es/personal/jetrini/objetos/HURST.pdf)

> It seems clear that H, calculated using GM1 and GM2 is sensible to the
> series average value (in fact, to the variation coefficient), so this
> fact has to be considered in robust analysis, because this means that
> a random series could apparently show memory, when what really happens
> is that the mean is not zero. In financial series, it means that in
> large horizons there will be a positive (or negative if the mean was
> negative) gain.

[meaning-of-the-Hurst-exponent](https://www.quora.com/Time-Series-What-is-the-meaning-of-the-Hurst-exponent)

> The three general types of financial data can be observed; trending,
> mean-reverting, or random walk. A trending data is one that increases
> or decreases over time (positive autocorrelation) while a
> mean-reverting data is one that fluctuates around its long-term
> equilibrium (negative autocorrelation). Random walk is the foundation
> of quantitative finance and is one of the first things a practitioner
> should understand. Financial data are assumed to follow a random walk
> and that implies that price movements are random and cannot be
> forecasted (zero autocorrelation). Our aim here is to understand which
> of the three types is the main characteristic of our data and that
> question can be answered through the Hurst exponent.
>
> Here’s the interpretations of it:
>
> H < 0.5 | mean-reverting data.
>
> H = 0.5 | geometric Brownian motion.
>
> H > 0.5 | trending data.

Comment: The average of my dataset is -3.25304. If I understand it right, it is possible that the Hurst value is lower than 0? In case of my dataset I have mean reverting data?

Comment: Could you explain more about your dataset?

Comment: My dataset are energy data of control energy [MWh]. They are more or less the difference between energy production and usage. It is needed to keep the electricity frequency in balance. I have this data from 2018-10-01 to 2020-05-12 in quarter-hourly values. Depending if there is more production or usage the value can be negative positve or 0

Comment: You can use log(cumsum(random.randn(100000)+1)+1000) in order to prevent negative values for hurst.